# To Fetch Top 2000 Records

Tags: ms-access, query-optimization, fetch

I have following query

strfinal = "
        TRANSFORM Format(Sum([Mandays].[Hours]),""#0.0"") AS [The Value] 
        SELECT
            Mandays.WorkTypeCode AS WONo, 
            Format(Sum([Mandays].[Hours]),""0000.0"") AS Total 
        FROM Mandays 
        GROUP BY Mandays.WorkTypeCode 
        PIVOT UCase([Ent By]); "

the query returns more than 2048 records and then it is not possible to show in VB6 MSHFLexGrid(Limit is 2048).
How do I **change query so that top 2000 records** must be fetched?

Comment: getting error "Values Specified in a TOP clause are not allowed in delete  queries or reports"

Comment: can anyone please correct the query?

Comment: Create a Query to get the right data, save it as a pre compiled query, then use TRANSFORM on that. The current setup you have will not prove effective.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way will be to do it like this:

```
CurrentDB.CreateQueryDef("tmpQuery", "SELECT Top 2000 * FROM Mandays")

strfinal = "TRANSFORM Format(Sum([tmpQuery].[Hours]),""#0.0"") AS [The Value] 
SELECT tmpQuery.WorkTypeCode AS WONo, Format(Sum([tmpQuery].[Hours]),""0000.0"") AS 
Total FROM tmpQuery GROUP BY tmpQuery.WorkTypeCode PIVOT UCase([Ent By]); "
```

You **could** put "Top 2000" after the SELECT statement in your current code, but doing it in another query will speed things up quite a bit.

If you like, you can also put an ORDER BY statement in the CreateQueryDef so you can control which 2000 records are used.

Comment: The table(Mandays) is having more than 14000 records.And after applying "GROUP BY Mandays.WorkTypeCode" the result comes up with near about 2100 tuples. And from that 2100 tuples I want to select only first 2000 tuples.

Comment: Did you try adding the "Top 2000" piece just after the SELECT statement in strFinal?

Comment: yes tried it but giving error "Values Specified in a TOP clause are not allowed in delete queries or reports"..

Comment: The only other option I can think of is to run a second query against strFinal and just take the top 2000 from that, then.  I'm not sure why it's not working in strFinal since it's not a delete query.